# Mac OS Sierra - Weather widget doesn't remember my city

Tags: macos

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.5 and the weather widget in the notifications drawer (that thing which you can toggle on the right side of the screen, which has "Today" and "Notifications" tabs) has a little but a bit annoying issue - it doesn't remember my city. When I add a city I have weather for it displayed, but after a system restart the widget doesn't contain any data and suggests me to add a city again. Nothing critical, but annoying. How can I make it remember cities I add and keep weather for them shown even after I restart my mac?

NB: I have location services disabled. Are they *required* for this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

If your Mac is logged in to your iCloud account and you have an iPhone also connected to iCloud, try adding the location into the **Weather** app on your iPhone.

Weather data is synchronized via iCloud between your Apple devices, and I’ve found that entering it on my Mac does not always push it to iCloud/the iPhone. Then when the Mac reboots, it tries to synchronize with iCloud and deletes the location.

Comment: I have an iphone synced to icloud as well and I have city added to the weather app on the iphone. The app behaves well on the iphone but I get the described behavior on the mac

Comment: I'm not aware of any link iCloud/Weather link for macOS and iOS... iOS 11 does have a Weather switch for iCloud...